# Deployment IIS MVC 4 - Routing fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller, web-deployment-project

I am trying to deploy my application on IIS, but it seems it won't work.

When I run the application on the localhost it gives me no problem, but deploying it on the IIS webserver it encounters some routing problem. I checked it with firebug and I see the post request sent do not find any target.

The request sent:

> http://xxxxx.com/Customer/CustomerListByFiter?jtStartIndex=0&jtPageSize=10

-> Not works (page not found?)

The local request sent on my localhost:

> ..../Customer/CustomerListByFiter?jtStartIndex=0&jtPageSize=10 -> Works

The Customer is my Controller class and CustomerListByfilter is the method with its parameters...

What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

I have build a sample application, this is the code which deploying to the webserver IIS generates an error (running it via Visual studio it works fine):

View:

```
   //Prepare jtable plugin
    $('#CustomerTable').jtable({
        title: 'xxx xxx',
        messages: germanMessages, //Localize table
        selecting: true, //Enable selecting
        multiselect: false, //Allow multiple selecting
        selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column
        paging: true,
        columnResizable: true, //Actually, no need to set true since it's default
        columnSelectable: true, //Actually, no need to set true since it's default
        saveUserPreferences: true, //Actually, no need to set true since it's default
        //selectOnRowClick: false, //Enable this to only select using checkboxes
        defaultSorting: 'CUST_LASTNAME ASC',
        actions: {
            listAction: '/Home/CustomerListByFiter'
        },
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CustomerListByFiter(string name = "", string lastName = "", int   
    cityId = 0, int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
    {
        List<customers> customers = null;
        try
        {
            if (name == "" && lastName == "")
                customers = CustomerList();
            else
            {
                customers = db.customers.Where(c => c.CUST_NAME == name || 
                c.CUST_LASTNAME == lastName).ToList();
            }

            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Json(new { Result = 
            "OK", Records = customers }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = customers, TotalRecordCount = customers.Count() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

I am pretty sure the problem is generated by the following call:
 listAction: '/Home/CustomerListByFiter' -> locally it works, remotely not.

System: IIS 7.5
        Windows Server 2008 R2
Deployed as Application

Comment: Have you deployed all the relevant .NET dll's related to MVC? The GAC on the server may not have them installed in which case you'll need to place them in your bin folder.

Comment: I tried to deploy all my project to IIS including bin folder containing all .dll's (System.Web.Mvc.dll etc.)....

Comment: Do you get any error messages in firebug?

Comment: Sending the request (POST) i get a general 404 Not Found message

Comment: Try <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> in your web.config

Comment: already tried but not solved it